# Detect other architectures of same product already installed in Wix

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have x86 and x64 installers of a product building from the same wix source.  What I'm looking at now is handling situations where a customer has installed the x86 software and attempts a Major Upgrade with x64 media, and vice versa.  I don't want to allow either of those to happen.

I had originally imagined looking for the presence of a HKLM/SOFTWARE registry key we set, but that won't work with x64 installed and an x86 upgrade - the latter won't be able to see it from the WOW64'd registry.

---

My current idea is to use two different UpgradeCodes for x86 and x64, and add some <Upgrade> trickery to have it abort if the other one is installed.  Is this the best way to go out about it, or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two UpgradeCodes is the right thing if you are splitting into two incompatible product lines, which seems to be the case because you want them mutually exclusive. In that case you could use an Upgrade search to detect the incompatible x86, except that FindRelatedProducts runs fairly late in the install after ALLUSERS has been chosen, maybe some dialogs shown, and has the (being picky) issue that you can't cross detect per user and per machine. So I don't like that solution.

I'd find an x86 component in the x86 product and search for it using an AppSearch for that component guid. That happens really early and can most likely be used in a launch condition because AppSearch is before LaunchConditions. Then the user doesn't see anything at all except a message saying they can't install this because that other product is installed. Or maybe a registry item or something that can be used as a launch condition to prevent the install at launch condition time.

Comment: I was able to do what you described in the first paragarph. An <Upgrade> done at FindRelatedProducts gets tested at LaunchConditions with a <Condition> element, and it works out.